# Error link 1104 while trying to add a library to a VC++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am trying to add a library *(opends60.lib)* in my visual C++ project. I have followed this instruction:

Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies:and then add *opends60.lib* to the list here.

if I build the code I see this error:

```
error LINK1104: cannot open file 'opends60.lib'
```

What schould I do to solve this problem?

Comment: >>What schould I do to solve this problem?
At least put 'opends60.lib' in your project dir.

Comment: I have put `opends.dll` in the directory too

Comment: .dll and .lib are two different files that must reside in different folders.
.dll - beside .exe, and .lib in folder where linker could find it during linkage.
.dll is a RUNTIME file, while .lib is a *project link time* file.

Comment: Make sure the .lib is in the search path for libraries. Also make sure you are not mixing 32 and 64 bit. You can not add a 64 bit library to a 32 bit application or viceversa.

Comment: Under Configuration Properties > Linker > General, you also need to add the directory where opends60.lib is to the "Additional Library Directories" section so Visual Studio knows where to find it.